# How to find your Google Shared Spaces?

Tags: google-workspace

I tried few hours ago the new [Google Shared Spaces](http://sharedspaces.googlelabs.com/) service. I create a space, but forgot to save the link.

Now, how can recover the space I was working on, without direct linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that now they have added the feature. Own spaces can be accessed by clicking [My Spaces](http://sharedspaces.googlelabs.com/p/inbox) link on user toolbar.